How to handle kafka commit message when data is not getting saved into data base
Net core and I am consuming messages from kafka. I have below implementation
  while(true)
  {
      var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

      if(consumeResult?.Message is not null)
      {
            // do processing
            // add data to list(some sample list every time I am adding data to list)
            // commit the message received
      }
  }

Now outside the while loop I am passing list(received data) to my database.
now my problem is in case I read all my messages and added to list but in data base some exception occurred and entire data is not saved into data base but I have already committed the message inside the while loop so if program executes again then I will not get data again because its already committed. So Can someone help me to handle this situation? Any help in t his regards appreciated. Thank you
